# How can I pass a std::vector<Vector3f> to my shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vector, projection-matrix

I have a `Vector3f` type which has `x`, `y`, and `z` properties. I have a `std::vector` of these vertices which describe my terrain.

I would like to pass these values to a vertex shader through a uniform variable, but all the OpenGL functions expect `GLfloat *`. Which is the best way to this? I would like to avoid conversions if possible.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Your uniforms has to fit in the CONSTANT BUFFER. don't be crazy, and put your vertices either in a VBO like everybody, or a 1-channel texture if you want to do displacement, or 3-channel if you want to store all 3 coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `location` is the uniform location you've already retrieved from the shader, and `vec` is your vector, then in C++11 you can do:

```
glUniform3fv(location, vec.size(), reinterpret_cast<GLfloat *>(vec.data()));
```

Prior to C++11:

```
glUniform3fv(location, vec.size(), reinterpret_cast<GLfloat *>(&vec[0]));
```

The "old" method will work in C++11 as well, but the [`data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) method codifies the intent better.

This *only* works if you've ensured your vertex structure is tightly packed: there cannot be any padding between elements, at the front of the structure, or the end of the structure. This will *usually* be the case by default for current compilers and platforms, but if you want to guarantee it you should look into the [pack pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) (for Microsoft's compiler) or the [packed attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) for GCC/LLVM compilers.

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm! Altough I needed to modify something else too to make my shader work this led me to the correct way. Thanks!

Comment: Take v.oddou's comment to heart though: this is not generally the way you want to pass a large amount of vertex data to your shader; it works well enough for *small* amounts of data, but for anything larger -- as terrain usually is -- you probably want to use an actual VBO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Vector3f class is laid out linear in memory.

```
std::vector<Vector3f> m_verts;

float* address = &m_verts[0].x;
```

This will get the address of the x value of the first element, so long as your data is laid out linearly, and your sizeof(Vector3f) == size(float) * 3 you should be fine.

Comment: I just re-red the title of your post, don't pass Vectors to gluniformmatrix4fv, you want glUniform3fv for a vector: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml